# Consulta usando Entityframework porquê a performance variação?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle, linq

Eu tenho as seguintes querys usando Linq to Object:

```
_Context.GerenciaTransacao.Where(x => x.Placa == "LUN1320").ToList();
```

nesta query, os resultados retornam em 100ms.

e

```
string placa = "LUN1320";

_Context.GerenciaTransacao.Where(x => x.Placa == placa).ToList();
```

já nesta, os resultados levam cerca de 3min para chegarem. Porquê essa variação tão grande?

eu preciso passar o valor em forma de parâmetro, mas não consegui resolver.

```
   SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO" AS "ID_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."COD_TRANSACAO" AS "COD_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."DSC_TRANSACAO" AS "DSC_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."PARTE_FIXA" AS "PARTE_FIXA", 
"Extent1"."PARTE_VARIAVEL" AS "PARTE_VARIAVEL", 
"Extent1"."RETORNO" AS "RETORNO", 
"Extent1"."NM_USUARIO" AS "NM_USUARIO", 
"Extent1"."HOST_ACESSO" AS "HOST_ACESSO", 
"Extent1"."DT_ALTERACAO" AS "DT_ALTERACAO", 
"Extent1"."PLACA" AS "PLACA", 
"Extent1"."CHASSI" AS "CHASSI"
FROM "DETROWEB"."TPL_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO" "Extent1"
WHERE ('LUN1320' = "Extent1"."PLACA")
```

Sql gerado no primeiro caso.

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO" AS "ID_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."COD_TRANSACAO" AS "COD_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."DSC_TRANSACAO" AS "DSC_TRANSACAO", 
"Extent1"."PARTE_FIXA" AS "PARTE_FIXA", 
"Extent1"."PARTE_VARIAVEL" AS "PARTE_VARIAVEL", 
"Extent1"."RETORNO" AS "RETORNO", 
"Extent1"."NM_USUARIO" AS "NM_USUARIO", 
"Extent1"."HOST_ACESSO" AS "HOST_ACESSO", 
"Extent1"."DT_ALTERACAO" AS "DT_ALTERACAO", 
"Extent1"."PLACA" AS "PLACA", 
"Extent1"."CHASSI" AS "CHASSI"
FROM "DETROWEB"."TPL_GERENCIA_TRANSACAO" "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1"."PLACA" = :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1"."PLACA" IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
```

Sql gerado no segundo caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido adicionando em cima da propriedade o atributo:

```
[Column("PLACA", TypeName = "varchar2")]
```

obrigado a todos que colaboraram.